Which episodes are the scenes depicting the "worst things Rick did to make sure someone else survived" from?
In the season 1 finale of The Walking Dead spinoff, The Walking Dead: The Ones Who Live, a series of clips from The Walking Dead are shown after Rick is asked by Beale, "What was the worst thing you did to make sure someone else survived?" These scenes suggest that these are Rick's most morally difficult choices made to save or protect those he cared about.
While I recognize some moments, like Rick killing Shane (S02E12) and biting out Joe's (Claimers leader) throat to save Carl (S04E16), I don't recall the other episodes. What episodes are these scenes from?

A scene depicts Rick delivering a downward machete strike to a man's head. Another man witnesses this act with a look of shock. It most likely occurred during Rick's group's time at the prison (Season 3 or 4).


Rick kills an unsuspecting bald man with a stab to the temple from behind.
 

Rick slashes the throat of a man sporting a backward baseball cap.
  




A scene depicts Rick delivering a downward machete strike to a man's head. It most likely occurred during Rick's group's time at the prison (Season 3 or 4).

This is Tomas, and the scene occurs in Season 3, Episode 2 -"Sick"




Rick kills an unsuspecting bald man with a stab to the temple from behind

This is one of the Terminus Butchers

Rick slashes the throat of a man sporting a backward baseball cap.

This is the second Terminus Butcher
Both scenes are from Season 5, Episode 1 - "No Sanctuary"




It's interesting that they went with Rick killing unnamed Terminus butchers instead of Rick killing their leader.
